# null value for state variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I've two async methods:

```
Future<void> checkForUpdate() async {
        InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate().then((info) {
            setState(() {
                _updateInfo = info;
                print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$_updateInfo');

            });
        }).catchError((e) => _showError(e));
    }


Future<void> doImmediateUpdate(AppUpdateInfo info) async{
       if(_updateInfo.immediateUpdateAllowed){
           await InAppUpdate.performImmediateUpdate();
       }

    }
```

`_updateInfo` is my state variable that I set in `checkForUpdate()` and use in `doImmediateUpdate`.

I'm calling both methods like this

```
`//.....'

    platformUpdates() async {
           if (Platform.isAndroid) {
               await checkForUpdate();
               await doImmediateUpdate(_updateInfo);
```

However I'm getting the error
`Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'immediateUpdateAllowed' was called on null.`

But the print statement for `_updateInfo` returns what I'm looking for..

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@InAppUpdateState{updateAvailable: true, immediateUpdateAllowed: true, flexibleUpdateAllowed: true, availableVersionCode: 14}
```

obviously there's something amiss in my code... 
cheers.

Comment: if you still want to use `InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate().then(...)` then return its value from `checkForUpdate` method

Comment: Do you check _updateInfo.immediateUpdateAllowed value? seem like the value of _updateInfo.immediateUpdateAllowed is null so it can't check the condition but it still get in await InAppUpdate.performImmediateUpdate(); inside the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *await* keyword instead of setting callbacks in *checkForUpdate*:

```dart
Future<void> checkForUpdate() async {
  final info = await InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate();

  setState(() {
    _updateInfo = info;
    print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$_updateInfo');
  });
}
```

When you set a callback using *then* and don't use *await* keyword, it doesn't wait for the future to resolve a value and just continues to execute the code - that's why variable in null. It would set state later when future is resolved. But when you use *await* keyword, code won't continue executing UNTIL future is resolved.

Execution order without **await**:

- *checkForUpdate* is called, *InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate* is called with Future object returned;
- Callback is set for Future object, *checkForUpdate* function is completed;
- *doImmediateUpdate* executes;
- (async gap before Future is resolved)
- Future callback for *checkForUpdate* is called and it sets state.

Execution order with **await**:

- *checkForUpdate* is called, *InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate* is called with Future object returned;
- Waiting for the Future to resolve;
- Setting variable in state, *checkForUpdate* function is completed;
- *doImmediateUpdate* executes.

Comment: will it make any difference? can you please explain why? Cause i have been using same callbacks and it works as expected. I mean is there any performance issue or anything like that if we use `then` instead of await? thanks

Comment: it made the difference ...Don't know why. Maybe a good question on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @SahdeepSingh It makes difference, because when you set a callback using _then_ it doesn't wait for the future to resolve - it just continues to execute code. That's why _updateInfo variable is null.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh I've updated the answer. I tried to explain the difference in execution order as good as I can.

Comment: thanks @IgorKharakhordin perfectly understood. Thanks again :)

Comment: and the quick fix is just to `return InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate().then(...)` - no really need for `await`

Comment: Yes, it is another approach. But I consider this as a bad code style (at least in this case). It creates more unnecessary syntax.